# Differentiation of integral of function product

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

For $f,g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ probability density functions and $F:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ the cumulative distribution function of $f$, must $\frac{d}{da}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F(a-y)g(y)dy=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(a-y)g(y)dy$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and the proof is very simple. Integrate the right side and apply Fubini's Theorem to see that the integral on the left side is the indefinite integral of the right side. Hence, the former is differentiable and the equation holds. I am writing the proof in words because the proof is so simple.